# Simple to follow guidance on update PHP from 4.3.10 to at least 5.1.1

Tags: mysql, linux, php5, ssh

I need to update my version of `PHP` to at least `5.1.1`, via SSH and need simple to follow advice on how to do it. We have a VPS (with Plesk) with webfusion, who won't update it for us and we need to get running `ModX`. I have searched the internet, with nothing that I can really understand, have a very limited knowledge of SSH and even little about how to update PHP.

Also as a sideline, will we need to update `MySQ`L? Currently running `3.23.58`

Comment: What distribution is the linux server running?  Different distributions will have different procedures.

Comment: And your MySQL version is extremely out of date, so upgrading is probably a good idea.  Actually, it's so far out of date I'm worried about the rest of your system - does anyone ever upgrade anything on this server?  Have security updates been installed?  It might be a better idea to start from scratch...

Comment: buy a new box, and installed with newer php/mysql, this does not ensure all your application can work properly due to certain feature/function has obsolete

Comment: Thanks for the comments, would webfusion be able to shift everything over in one shot? Bit concerned about email etc.

Answer (score 1):

Is it feasible for you to get an entirely new VPS, and just migrate over your data?  Plesk should make it somewhat simple to create and restore a backup.

Going from MySQL 3.x to 5.1 (latest GA) is not going to be a fun process.  It's going to involve creating a backup then restoring the backup, you will not be able to let MySQL upgrade itself and keep your data.

Have you considered any type of managed hosting (instead of your current unmanaged)?  If you don't know what you are doing with SSH, it might be worth the money.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about free migrations from tech support at any ISP.  I have worked for several and sometimes migrations go well and sometimes they go horribly wrong.  Also, your control panel version will limit upgrade paths for PHP & MySQL.

If your site is critical to you, I would go on elance and hire a sys admin with a good record of customer satisfaction to do it for you.